# Explicit example of a function with Fourier transform in $C_0^\infty(\mathbb{R})$

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis, functional-analysis, fourier-analysis, analyticity

Is anyone aware of an explicit example of a (Schwartz, real-analytic, extending to an entire function with suitable decay properties along imaginary directions as for the Paley–Wiener-Schwartz theorem) function $\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{C}$ whose Fourier transform is in $C^\infty_0(\mathbb{R}; \mathbb{C})$?

I'm hoping to find one such example written in a form simple enough to be suitable for computation (*not* as an inverse Fourier transform of a $C^\infty_0$ function!).

I found somewhere the claim that
$$ f(x) = \frac{\sin(\pi x)}{\sin(\pi \sqrt x) \sinh(\pi \sqrt x))} $$
works, but sadly I'm unable to verify this. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Doesn't your requirement that it extends to an entire function imply that the Fourier transform has compact support?

Comment: Isn't the most likely way of doing this going to be to take a $C_0^\infty$ function and explicitly compute its inverse Fourier transform?

Comment: You should define what suitable decay along imaginary axis means, because Paley-Wiener is an iff-statement.